# Storage account used by VM Data disk

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

When I designed my ARM template for a SQL VM, I used three different resource group to segregate the resources.

For e.g Vnet, created a resource group just for the vnets. In that group I create multiple vnet. Let say one vnet for Dev and another for Test etc. 
Every DEV server share the same dev vnet, Test server share the Test Vnet.

Likewise, one resource group storage account. For each server I create a dedicated storage account instated of a shared storage account. Each server has 4 disk.

How can I identify which storage account used by the VM and on which account data disk is?

Please see the link below for the template

[ARM Template](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mi0i4pP9d-vKqwChPGALRwRVvM-sRO3Y)

Thanks

Comment: Hi - This doesn't answer your question but for the last year or so we have had managed disks which mean you don't need a storage account - i'd 100% migrate to that and put the managed disks in the same resource group as the VM - everything about this is better

Comment: Thanks Ed, does this mean we don't need storage account for a VM?

Comment: not for disks, i stilld eploy one for vm diagnostics but managed disks are the way forward :)